# Angular2 app public URL without port number

Tags: angular, wakanda

What I have to config to access an Angular2 app from a remote server without a port number. 
For example: My server where wakanda is running is www.myserver.com and my Angular2 app is reachable via localhost:8000. Now I'll use something like www.myserver.com/myapp/ to see my Angular2 app.
I've found the webpack.config.js, but no idea whether this is the right place to do it or what config to set.

Answer (score 0):

Check your protractor.conf.js file. In this file change your baseUrl.

```
baseUrl: 'your base url',
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea about what wakanda is, but only point you have to mind is your baseUrl, which for your localhost seems to be "/" and you want it to be "/myapp" in production.

You'll need to set it up in index.html inside the head tag like this:

```
<head>
  <base href="/myapp">
  ...
</head>
```

And in webpack config

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/myapp',
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Public URLs by default map to port 80. You can specify `ng serve --port 80` in your `package.json` file in your Angular2 directory so that the application is accessible without specifying port.